# Adding spaces to CartoDB HTML

Tags: carto, html

Is there a way to add a **non-breaking space** to CartoDB legends or info windows?

For instance, I have the following legend:

[image]

But now I would like to add some spaces to that legend. I used the following approach:

```
<div class='cartodb-legend choropleth'> 
  <div class="legend-title">Hello &nbsp StackExchange</div>
<ul>
  <p>Just adding &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp some text... </p>
    <li class="min">
     ...
```

As you can see the **&nbsp** is highlighted in the code:

[image]

But it somehow is not translated, and shows up like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add ";" at the end:

```
<div class='cartodb-legend custom'> 
<div class="legend-title">this is &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   my     title</div>
<ul>
<li>
    ...
</li>
```

[image: Spaces]

PS:

[image: HELP]

Comment: Of course... one of the things I always forget!

Comment: I am also trying to use <i> or <em>. Neither seem to work. Is this not supported or am I missing a little detail as well?